# C# - I can't dump to a file the output of my process-ish

Tags: c#, variables, process, dump

I've been messing around with C# and in one moment of the code, I need to dump the output of an external .exe into a .txt. I do it by starting cmd.exe and then loading the program, with its attributes plus the `>` opperator. But now, when I execute the program, the file isn't even created. Meanwhile, if I input the EXACT same code that is passed to cmd in the program:

> "o:\steam\steamapps\common\counter-strike global offensive\bin\demoinfogo.exe" "O:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\testfile.dem" -gameevents -nofootsteps -deathscsv -nowarmup > "o:\steam\steamapps\common\counter-strike global offensive\demodump.txt"

directly into the Command Prompt, it **does** get dumped. I've been looking around, and I found **A LOT** of info, but sadlly nothing has helped me enough so far, so I decided to ask myself.
I attach the chunks of code that I think are relevant to this.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    arguments += " -gameevents";
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        arguments += " -nofootsteps";
    }
    if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        arguments += " -extrainfo";
    }
}
if (checkBox4.Checked)
{
    arguments += " -deathscsv";
    if (checkBox5.Checked)
    {
        arguments += " -nowarmup";
    }
}

if (checkBox6.Checked)
{
    arguments += " -stringtables";
}
if (checkBox7.Checked)
{
    arguments += " -datatables";
}
if (checkBox8.Checked)
{
    arguments += " -packetentites";
}
if (checkBox9.Checked)
{
    arguments += " -netmessages";
}
if (dumpfilepath == string.Empty)
{
    dumpfilepath =  getCSGOInstallationPath() + @"\demodump.txt";
}

baseOptions = @"""" + demoinfogopath + @"""" + " " + @"""" + demofilepath + @"""" + arguments;
startInfo.Arguments = baseOptions + " > " + @"""" + dumpfilepath + @"""";

try  
{
    using (exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
         ....a bunch of code...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Process` class that you're creating has this useful little property:

[**Process.StandardOutput**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When a Process writes text to its standard stream, that text is normally displayed on the console. By redirecting the StandardOutput stream, you can manipulate or suppress the output of a process. For example, you can filter the text, format it differently, or write the output to both the console and a designated log file.

All you need to do is ensure you're redirecting the StandardOutput to this stream (using the `RedirectStandardOutput` property in the `ProcessStartInfo`) and then you can read the output from that stream. Here's the MSDN sample code, slightly abridged:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(args[0], "spawn");
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // important!
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // also important!
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();

// Here we're reading the process output's first line:

StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the help for CMD (access by typing `CMD /?`) you'll see the following options:

```
/C   Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates 
/K   Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Without one of those switches, CMD won't interpret the string you provide it as a command to execute.

When I write a short program like the following, it successfully generates a file... *but only if* I use either the `/C` or `/K` options:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

var command = @"echo test > c:\users\myusername\Desktop\test.txt";
var args = "/C " + command;
startInfo.Arguments = args;

using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo)) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hi you could try this to build your process like this.
public class Launcher
{
    public Process CurrentProcess;
    public string result = null;

    public Process Start()
    {
        CurrentProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\",
                FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe")
            }
        };
        CurrentProcess.Start();

        return CurrentProcess;
    }

    //Start the process to get the output you want to add to your .txt file:
    private void writeOuput()
    {
        Currentprocess = new process();
        Start()

        CurrentProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Your CMD");
        CurrentProcess.StandardInput.Close();

        result = CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.Close()

        //Then to put the result in a .txt file:
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"C:\path.txt", result);
    }
}
```

}